# Magento 2 custom theme layout xml and css not working

Tags: layout, theme, css

I created a new theme and it was working fine but after a few days, I realized some things weren't working.

default_head_blocks.xml is no longer pulling in any css files that I include (both hosted and external)

default.xml  is not overwriting parent one.

I'm not sure what is causing this. I even tried deleting /var/ folder as well as /pub/static/frontend/

Comment: Have you tried deploying content? `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 66):

Check your DB. There is a table called `theme` that stores a reference to all the themes that have ever been installed in your store. If the `type` of the theme is set to 1, that means Magento sees the theme are virtual (what ever that means) and will no longer load your xml files. If that is the case, just change it to 0. I don't know the why of this issue, but it has tripped me up a few time.

[image]

Comment: That is very interesting! I tried that but i didn't do anything but I also didn't restart mamp either.

I did end up creating a new theme folder and copying and pasting previous theme to new theme folder and it's working but some of the other stuff that is normally on the site doesn't get displayed (like all the top links). Very odd indeed.

Comment: That is odd. When running into this exact issue, this was the solution for me, i'm very interested what might be causing your problem. When i run into issues like this, I just clean out all the var folder's content (but not the folders themselves) and everything in `pub/static` and recompile. 9 time out of 10, this clears everything up.

Comment: This fixed it for me!
I had to set this type value to '0' in the Database. After that I recompiled en deployed all static content. Finally my layout XML's where loaded again! 
Still no idea how this database type got set to 1 :S

Thank you @circlesix

Comment: I happens when you perform some kind of magic incantation while compiling. No idea what that is yet, but that's when that value can get changed.

Comment: Is it possible to set the type from anywhere in the admin?

Comment: I don't think so, but i know they have done a lot of changes to the way the theme is set in the admin since i posted this, and i haven't gone back to check.

Comment: Oh My god... I have been stumbling around in the dark for no lie the past 16 hours... Freaking Magento! Thank you so much.

Comment: I have still not tracked down why or where the "type" is set. It would be nice to know what is triggering this setting and how to stop it.

Comment: You are a legend! I'd been searching for it for hrs and for one point thought that it's something to do 2.1 to 2.2 upgrade. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Thanks! for quick patch, reporting it to magento2.

Comment: I hope that will be fixed very soon https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4330

Comment: You saved my day... but why it happens ? any reason for that ?

Comment: @sameer, I never followed up with any research on why this happens. But it's still happening so many years later.

Comment: @circlesix, I faced same issue. Theme type "1" considering theme as virtual. will research on that and update you.

Comment: Ran into this in 2.3.4. Finally figured out that layout xml wasn't being loaded and that led me here. There is a function, Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Registration::checkPhysicalThemes, which loops through all registered themes and sets them to virtual if the folder is not found in the filesystem. Not exactly sure how it is triggered, but it seems that if you are messing around with themes and make a change in the admin while a theme folder is not in its expected location (or maybe permissions are off?), it will be automatically set to virtual. Unhelpful, Magento.

Comment: Just leaving it here that you need to run setup upgrade, static content deployment and cache clean for the changes done to the DB to be reflected on frontend.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue is not fixed after set type=0. Then I figured out we are running Magento with default mode. Issue fixed after switched to production mode.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Bilal, changing with type=0 in the **theme** table, did not work for me also.

What Worked for me in my **Magento2.3.4**

1. Reverted back to type=1 in theme table.
2. Change **Mode** to **Developer Mode** - Run

   `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer && php bin/magento cache:clean`
3. In **Developer Mode** - You will see XML errors.
4. Check the **System.log**, It may also contains errors, **Fix the errors** - **See Screenshot**
5. **Run**

   `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`

   `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set default`

   `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

   `php bin/magento cache:clean`

***Now your layout should start working***

[image]