# top link edit Luma magento 2

Tags: magento2, toplinks

I'm trying to change the **top links** "**Compare Products My Account Create an Account Sign In**". This a **child theme**. I've attempted to change both the `default.xml` and `layout.xml` in my layout directory. Nothing works.

Shouldn't I be able to do this through admin?

this is **2.0.13** running locally on a mac

Answer (score 0):

You aren't able to do this in the admin, but you weren't able to do this in the admin in m1 either.

But you are on the right track, but the way you need to do this is in the `default.xml` of the theme module. Create a file here:

**app/design/frontend/{vendor_namespace}/{theme_name}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

And include this code:

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="gag-my-quote" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Your Custom Link</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">your/custom/link</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

It is possible to add in a block into the header that calls a cms block (for future ease of use), it's not that hard to do and can be done in this same file, if you want help setting that up, let me know.

Comment: Hm, I tried that and still get no changes. Flushed my cache.

Comment: I'm using blank as the parent, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: I might be confused, but i thought you were using a custom theme based on  Luma, is that the case? For the .xml file that you are using, can you get anything to work? As in, can you add anything in or can you use a `remove` statement to get anything to remove? I'm thinking that your issue might be the file location or the naming of the file. You shouldn't need to clean cache when making an xml edit. Also, take a look here, this has tripped me up a bunch: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134523/magento-2-custom-theme-layout-xml-and-css-not-working/134534#134534