# How to override catalog_product_view.xml?

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.3, xml, frontend

I want to have a different theme on special products.
So I have a main theme 
--> app/design/frontend/Main/Default
and I want a different theme, which is child of my main:
-- app/design/frontend/Special/Default

How can I override the catalog_product_view.xml in the special theme, based on main theme? Placing the xml in the "Magento_Catalog/layout/" doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

To override the XML add your XML file here:

```
app\design\frontend\Main\Special\Magento_Catalog\layout\override\theme\Main\Default\catalog_product_view.xml
```

Over to extend it:

```
app\design\frontend\Main\Special\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
```

Comment: Hi Ben, yes I want to extend and redesign some elements. But it doesnt work. My path is: 
'app/design/frontend/Special/Default/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml'
Overriding show the error: "Wrong Price Rendering layout configuration. Factory block is missed"

Comment: That sounds like you have overridden it successfully but there is something in the original file you need to carry over. The way you're extending looks to be ok, have you tried making some changes and check if they apply?

Comment: This solved my problem. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134523/magento-2-custom-theme-layout-xml-and-css-not-working