# Creating a custom theme for Magento2 from the Luma theme as parent

Tags: magento2, css, xml, luma-theme, custom-theme

Referencing this article below:

https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/create-a-custom-child-theme-from-luma-theme/

Having followed all of the steps, our theme is created and applied, but none of the files are being read.

So for example, the content of the default.xml is not being applied to the site.

Any ideas of possible reasons why?

I found this article:

[Magento 2 custom theme layout xml and css not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134523/magento-2-custom-theme-layout-xml-and-css-not-working)

But this isn't the issue. We have the type as 0 not 1 there.

None of the xml or CSS files we have uploaded are being read. For example, applying a Google font, is not showing in the  section of the source pages of any page. Static files have been deployed, cache cleared etc. But not overriding the Luma theme.

Answer (score 0):

And does that mean you have deployed the content?

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

this is discussed here:
[Magento 2 custom theme layout xml and css not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134523/magento-2-custom-theme-layout-xml-and-css-not-working)

Comment: Yes, content already deployed. We use this query for that - php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f --jobs=4

Comment: kk and you've updated the file default_head_blocks.xml (as luma uses, just lift and shift)?

Comment: Yes. In this location - /app/design/frontend/Magento/nordicoutdoor/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.html

Comment: Great, so the less you written is being deployed right?
'php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy' maybe force it too, any good?

Comment: The files are being deployed, just not picked up and the xml and css files within the child theme folders are not being read for example.

Comment: That's strange!? Can't see the example you wanted to provide, also i should check you are using grunt tasks here, so grunt less, watch etc, I want clear if when you said deployed you were seeing the changes in either var or pub folders?